# Detect when building for archive

Tags: swift, xcode, archive, nslog

Is it possible to recognize when the build is made for archive? 
I have debug/release flags, and I want to print the app's logs at debug and hide them at release version.
I can do that with  #if debug...#else...#endif

What I'm asking is, is it possible to archive the app (with release build configuration) and to show all the logs (while still hiding them if the build is not for archive) ?